# Filter packets with iptables on a tap interface

Tags: networking, iptables, virtualization, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to write firewall rules to prevent a guest machine from accessing the internet.
The server (Ubuntu server 22.0, using KVM) has a physical connection (enp34s0), which is connected to the router,a bridge interface (br0) and the guest is using a tap device (vnet0) which is bridged to the same network with br0.
Any rule that I've tried to apply on vnet0 didn't work.

For example I tried to prevent ping with the following commands:
`iptables -I FORWARD -i vnet0 -o br0 -p icmp -j DROP`
`iptables -I FORWARD -o vnet0 -i br0 -p icmp -j DROP`
`iptables -I FORWARD -i vnet0 -o enp34s0 -p icmp -j DROP`
`iptables -I FORWARD -o enp34s0 -i br0 -p icmp -j DROP`

still I'm able to send pings from/to the guest.
(also tried with -p tcp --dport 443 to prevent https)
Am I doing something wrong?
Can't figure out if it related to the fact that it's a TAP device
and didn't find anything related on the web..

Comment: If an answer solves you problem you can (and should) 'accept' it by clicking on the checkmark besides the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a logging rule to your `FORWARD` table to capture any ICMP traffic...

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p icmp -j LOG --log-prefix 'FORWARD_ICMP '
```

...you'll see that the input interface is the bridge, not the TAP device:

```
Sep 09 19:19:20 fizzgig kernel: FORWARD_ICMP IN=virbr0 OUT=wlp0s20f3
PHYSIN=vnet1 MAC=52:54:00:f7:70:2a:52:54:00:18:f8:12:08:00 SRC=192.168.122.210
DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=59668 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8
CODE=0 ID=5 SEQ=1
```

This means that your rules with `-i vnet0` are never going to match.

You can see the TAP device in the `PHYSIN` attribute. We can match this using the `physdev` module, like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vnet1 -j DROP
```

(There is also a --physdev-out match if you need to match traffic in the other direction.)

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.